# Debate - Invoke webservice from Database layer or Java layer?

Tags: java, oracle, design-patterns, database-design, architecture

Which is a good approach to invoke a webservice (SOAP) ?
Is it from a Java layer or in the Oracle Database layer ?
My database colleague is fighting to implement that in the Database layer instead of Java layer.

**Update:-**

Briefly we have a web application that manages data in Oracle database. Later we need to sync some of these data to an external application through a webservice (SOAP) provided by that third party.

**Reasons to be in Java layer**

These are my own considerations to be in Java layer,

1. For security reasons DB host can be isolated from public internet access and would not have any access to the world.
2. A Java webservice client can be deployed in an Application server and exploit its features like scalability, etc
3. ??

Comment: Not a lot of experience in the area, but my thinking is, what does SOAP have to do with the database?  SOAP is a result of some interaction with a possible data source, but it has very little to do with the database.  Wouldn't that expose the database to at a much easier to reach point then say, having a service layer between the web and the database to process the request - IMHO

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the layers you mention correspond to technologies. 
I would say that you definite have to call the Web Service from the Java Layer.
However the functionality performed by that Web Service would determine in what architecture layer it should be called. So you should think about whether it is a Business related Web Service or a data persistence related Web Service.
It is most of the times a good idea to have a set services that perform CRUD functionalities in separate layer inside your so called "java layer" .

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking this question as I googled and came to know that SOAP webservices can be called from Oracle PL/SQL also. Without knowing this my piece of advice would also have been to do it in the Java layer. But now I think differently.

Since the purpose of your web service call is purely data-sync - I would suggest that you write a stored proc in PL/SQL which calls the web-service. You can schedule the stored proc execution using Oracle scheduler as per the data-sync frequency.

The reason for my answer is - if you only want to sync data at periodic intervals then writing a java based scheduled job which opens a database connection, fetches data to be synced from database to java layer, then makes a SOAP call, gets the SOAP response and then updates the tables by opening a database connection(although you can use batch updates but still), is definitely a more resource-consuming\time-consuming way rather than just doing a direct database-to-SOAP-and-back communication using PL/SQL based web service calls.

Comment: Thanks, I agree for such a usecase it would perfectly make sense to be in DB. But with one possible issue.... opening  up the internet access to DB server and expose sensitive data to world with possible attacks ?

Comment: Security would be a consideration but then Oracle being an established server 'should' be taking care of it. This article I found(https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chtwelve.htm#JJDEV13475) doesn't list any such vulnerability - but I am not a database/network security expert. So, before you proceed please make sure about the security aspects of an Oracle database server.